# How do you refresh formulas in OpenOffice/LibreOffice Calc?

Tags: libreoffice, openoffice.org

I started using LibreOffice and when I had laid out the formulas I pressed F9 like I normally did in Excel and nothing happened.

I couldn't figure out the keyboard shortcut to refresh and neither could I find it in the application menu.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

**Simple Recalculation:**

Recalculates all changed formulas. If AutoCalculate is enabled, the Recalculate command applies only to formulas like RAND or NOW.

Choose **Data - Calculate - Recalculate**

F9

Press <kbd>F9</kbd> to recalculate. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> to recalculate all formulas in the document.

After the document has been recalculated, the display is refreshed. All charts are also refreshed.

The Add-In functions like RANDBETWEEN currently cannot respond to the Recalculate command or <kbd>F9</kbd>. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> to recalculate all formulas, including the Add-In functions.

*Source: http://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Recalculate*

**References to Other Sheets and Referencing URLs or other external data**

See source: http://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/References_to_Other_Sheets_and_Referencing_URLs*

Comment: When I wrote my custom function, use it in one cell and update it's formula in Macro editor, I need to recalculate (CTRL + SHIFT + F9) cells to see effects. Even if I edit cell (F2 button) and I hit ENTER, I do not see updated formula (as long as I will not use CTRL + SHIFT + F9). I think that this "feature" might be a source of confusion.

Comment: This works, but the root cause for me was under use of memory. If you go to Tools-Options-LibreOffice-Memory I raised the amount for Libreoffice to use up higher (I used 2 GB) and the Memory per object (100 MB worked well). This made the entire program run smoother and recalculate on it's own.

Comment: not working for me - I'm really wondered that a simple concatenation is not updated. and I'm wondering how reliable is calc when it does not even update calculations when I reoppen a document

Answer (score 2):

I found that if I pasted in an empty cell from where the formulas worked, then I could edit cells in the inserted column and they would evaluate. Of course, I had to do this for the entire column

Answer (score 1):

I have found that if I insert a column between two existing columns, any formula I put into that column does not evaluate.

Recalculating does not help.

Putting the same formula into a column that was already part of the spreadsheet works properly.

Answer (score 1):

As they wrote in [other page](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/12165/calc-auto-recalc-does-not-work/?answer=19044#post-id-19044):

LibreOffice intentionally does not recalculate older spreadsheets, because as formulas are updated from version to version or between different spreadsheet programs, the results can be different. Go to Tools > Options > Formula> LibreOffice Calc, under 'Recalculation on file load', change the two drop-downs, 'Excel 2007 and newer' and 'ODF Spreadsheet (not saved by LibreOffice)', to 'Always recalculate'. Click Ok, close the spreadsheet and LibreOffice. Now open the file in LibreOffice and you should see that the formulas have recalculated.

Also go to Data > Calculate [previously it was Tools > Cell Contents] and be sure that AutoCalculate is selected.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace '=' by '=' in all sheets.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>, mark 'Search in all sheets', Replace All '=' by '='

Answer (score 0):

I discovered this accidentally: Select an empty cell then tap the delete key. The refresh is immediate and is always ready to go again. Unlike the enter key, it's active cell remains in the same cell. Try this. Select a random cell on a blank spreadsheet. Enter  =ROUND(RAND()*99)   Hit the delete key as fast or slow as you like. The formula will return values between 00 and 99. Every time that you tap the delete key the sheet is refreshed and the formula recalculates. Press and Hold the delete key down will instantly refresh to show a new number just long enough read it then the process becomes continuous blur of refreshing numbers. Probably refreshing every other millisecond, and the cell is a blur of double digit Numbers until the delete key is released.
Shakesbeer 2017-Jan-03